# Trying to have "Yes" "No" label to the left of my question using HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code which currently puts "Yes" and "No" radio buttons to the right side of the question. How can I have these radio buttons to the left side of the question instead of right?

```
<table class="table100" width="150%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td class="data_xx"> Are you in high school?</td>
<td class="data_yy">
<input type="radio" name="jack" id="jack" value="Y" onclick="hideShowJacks('Y');"/><label>Yes</label>

<input type="radio" name="jack" id="jack" value="N" checked onclick="hideShowJacks('N');"/><label>No</label>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Put the <td> for the inputs before the <td> for the question. <td> elements are ordered left to right

Comment: So put the label on the other side of the input?

Comment: So as Ted Brownlow mentioned elements are ordered, so the elements for yes/no goes above the question if you want them to be appeared before your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do that.

To keep it simple and consistent with your current format you can just place the input tags before the question as such:

```
<table class="table100" width="150%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
      <td class="data_yy">
          <input type="radio" name="jack" id="jack" value="Y" onclick="hideShowJacks('Y');"/><label>Yes</label>
          <input type="radio" name="jack" id="jack" value="N" checked onclick="hideShowJacks('N');"/><label>No</label>
      </td>
      <td class="data_xx"> Are you in high school?</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Another way to do this if you do not want to change your html structure is to use CSS:

```
<table class="table100" width="150%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr class="questionContainer">
    <td class="data_xx">Are you in high school?</td>
    <td class="data_yy">
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="jack"
        id="jack"
        value="Y"
        onclick="hideShowJacks('Y');"
      /><label>Yes</label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="jack"
        id="jack"
        value="N"
        checked
        onclick="hideShowJacks('N');"
      /><label>No</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<style>
  .questionContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks @ ThatFrenchComputerGuy. I will be using only html for now. so as you suggested I tried that too earlier, but when I do that, I see only "Yes" "No" radio buttons, but the "question" some reason hides(doesn't appear), and I don't know if something to do with the width in the table class.

Comment: Have you tried copying and pasting my answer ?
Here you can see it working:
https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-dawn-be082?file=/index.html

If it still doesn't I suggest you check your entire code for missing closing tags (</>) or or other spelling mistakes.
Let us know how it goes !

Answer (score 0):

I found what the issue was. what I forgot to mention in my above code was that I had css in this two classes(class="data_xx **xxx1**" and class="data_yy **yyy1**". They were missing in the original above which caused the alignment issue.

```
<table class="table100" width="150%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
 <tr>        
    <td class="data_yy yyy1">
       <input type="radio" name="jack" id="jack" value="Y" onclick="hideShowJacks('Y');"/><label>Yes</label> 
        <input type="radio" name="jack" id="jack" value="N" checked onclick="hideShowJacks('N');"/><label>No</label>
   </td>
   <td class="data_xx xxx1"> Are you in high school?</td>
</tr>
```

After I removed these two values(xxx1 and yyy1),the question and yes/no buttons came out right, and of course the question goes below the input type radio buttons. Thank you for the suggestions.